# Delete nodes from XML with attribute and namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have the next `XML` file

```
<files>
   <mainFile num="333">
      <DE>
        <file>
        </file>
        <file>
        </file>
      </DE>
    </mainFile>

  <mainFile num="444">
     <DE /> 
  </mainFile>

   <mainFile num="555">
     <DE>
        <file>
       </file>
        <file>
       </file>
        <file>
       </file>
    </DE>
  </mainFile>

   <mainFile num="666">
     <TLL>
     </TLL>
   </mainFile>

  </files>
```

I want to delete from each node `<mainFile num="<number>">` all what inside `<DE>` - only if it's called `<DE>`, in case of other nodes inside like `<TLL>` in the example, do not touch it.

my idea is to get something like this:

```
<files>
    <mainFile num="333"> </mainFile> 
    <mainFile num="444"> </mainFile>
    <mainFile num="555"> </mainFile>
    <mainFile num="666">
     <TLL>
     <TLL>
    </mainFile>
 </files>
```

Any ideas how can I implement it?

I tried :

```
            var xmlString = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
            xmlString.XPathSelectElements("//DE").Remove();

xmlString .Element("DE").Remove();
```

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do it. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Any question other than implying *write this for me*

Comment: Yes I tried, I added the basic of what I tried

Comment: And what is your actual error/output you get with the code you tried? (Let me guess, does it have something to do with `</TLL>` being on summer vacation, perhaps? ;) )

Comment: summer vacation? WHAT?

Comment: @dotnetom I tried few things, but all of them don't delete it as I want to

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

    XmlNodeList nodeList;
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

    nodeList=root.SelectNodes("descendant::mainFile");

foreach (XmlNode n in nodeList)
    {
      XmlNodeList des = n.SelectNodes("descendant::DE");
      foreach (XmlNode de in nodeList)
      {
        de.ParentNode.RemoveChild(de); 

      }     
    }
```